# Android splash screen not appearing correctly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When the app is loading, instead of a proper splash screen it just shows, the best way to describe it, when you go to install an app from the Play store, the black screen with the icon in the top left corner and some text, that's all it shows when launching my app...

I narrowed it down to activity_game.xml as when looking in the Graphical Layout of that file, it just shows a boring black screen with text.

How would I change this to incorporate a full screen image on splash instead?

Let's say for example, the image is called 'loading.png'

Content of activity_game.xml is below;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".GameActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

--- Edit -

Thanks Rod, works to the point I now get a black screen on launch, I copied loading.png into the drawable folder and use the code like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GameActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/loading"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Not sure why it is not loading the image?

Comment: so you want to put image instead of text?

Comment: That text 'hello world' does not actually show when the app loads, but it shows in Graphical layout - I would prefer it to be a full screen image as a loading, before the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your activity full screen by setting the theme to no title bar into your activity tag of the manifest and add this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Dont add padding to the `RelativeLayout` to avoid the black screen border, instead of TextView use the ImageView to create an image to the layout.

**sample:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GameActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="your_drawable_image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @user3355723 post the code where you used this layout

Comment: @user3355723 cant see it.

Comment: @user3355723 GameActivity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55737/discussion-between-user3355723-and-rod-algonquin).